# Fabric Extender for Peer-Link on vPC domain (two Nexus 5000 switches)

Tags: switch, cisco-nexus, sfp

I have two Nexus 5000 series switches.  My question lies with the Peer Link.  My intentions are to use e1/31 and e1/32 on both switches as the peer link.  Here are the exact SFPs that I am using for the Peer Link:

```
Ethernet1/31
    transceiver is present
    type is Fabric Extender Transceiver
    name is CISCO-JDSU
    part number is PLRXPL-VC-S43-CG
    revision is B
    serial number is J_________Q
    nominal bitrate is 10300 MBit/sec
    Link length supported for 50/125um OM3 fiber is 100 m
    Link length supported for 62.5/125um fiber is 10 m
    cisco id is --
    cisco extended id number is 4
```

I have tried to configure these properly and I'm unable to get the peer-link running over these Fabric Extender style SFPs.  I'm curious if I have to use SFPs that carry Data instead for the Peer-Link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the FET (as it's known) is limited to only function on links to/from fabric extenders. It can't be used to connect two switches. You'll need to go find an actual SFP-10G-SR (or equivalent) to get the links to come up.

Comment: The switch treats it differently. There's nothing fundamentally different about it. (it's just a shorter range optic)

Comment: oh?  @Ricky So I *CAN* use them as peer-link SFPs?

Comment: NO, *because the switch software won't let you.* Cisco won't allow a "cheap"(er) FET to be used here. (Not that Cisco isn't over charging for every optic signed with their [not so secret] magic sauce)